# Only one external screen deteced and the other one is mirrored

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I am very new to Ubuntu.  I have dell laptop E5440 with Ubuntu 14.04 connected to a dock with 2 DVI-D port and one VGI port.  I am trying to setup my two HP external screens to be extended but I am not able to. The main issue is I see only monitor, the other one is mirrored to it no matter what I do and I have only Intel® Haswell Mobile is my graphic card.

this is my xrandr command

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768       60.0 +   40.0 
   1360x768       59.8     60.0 
   1024x768       60.0 
   800x600        60.3     56.2 
   640x480        59.9 
DP1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   3200x900       60.0 
   2560x1024      60.0 
   1280x1024      60.0 
   1440x900       59.9 
   1280x720       60.0 
   1024x768       60.0 
   800x600        60.3 
   640x480        60.0 
   720x400        70.1 
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any idea how I can solve this

Thanks